# Difference between react and react admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Right now i am going to do project in react admin. I need to know the difference between react and react admin. Iam using the link https://marmelab.com/react-admin/

Comment: Okay, good luck doing the research! Looks like you've already found the link to the library. Be sure to let us know when you have any code related questions!

Comment: This is a little like asking for the differences between a tree and an apple. They are related, but fundamentally different things, you will need to be more specific about what you want to know.

Comment: I don't know react. i am from microsoft .net background. that is why iam asking. recently i got project using react admin

Answer (score 2):

**React** is a library that enables you to build web applications based on the component concept, and it represents the V "view" in the MVC pattern. **React-Admin** is a Web Framework for B2B applications, built using **React**.